# Ubuntu 15.10 DVD iso when boots is unreadable on a new PC with gtx 745 card

Tags: nvidia

I recently purchased a Dell 8700 with a GTX 745 video card for improving speed performance for financial and statistical programming that I write. I prefer high performance chips but am not a gamer.

My issue is with the graphics card. When I created a boot CD for Ubuntu 15.10 the monitor display through the VGA port shows the screen with many letters in the text missing. Since I've installed Ubuntu 15.10 before I muddled through the unreadable screens and managed to install. Once Ubuntu 15.10 installed on the hard drive the same unreadable screens came up. Luckily the terminal screens were not so affected by this issue. I compiled the Nvidia Kernel and then installed the package provided via their site and viola the video display came up in a very readable state. So I was able to resolve the video problem on a hard drive install.

The problem is that I could not resolve how to fix the video problem running off a Live CD. I've called Nvidia tech support and their answer is the card won't support the Live CD version of Ubuntu 15.10. OK so the next question that I asked was is there any other product you sell that would resolve this problem. No real clear answer on this either from their tech support.  I wrote to AMD and they claim that their Video cards will support most Live CD's based on Linux. Great, get an AMD card seemed to be the solution. But then after reading several articles  it seems the AMD Radeon R9 card is the worst thing to happen to Linux while the NVidia 900 series has been a real improvement.

I've had other display issues with multiple Live CD's that I use. Clonezilla, although the text is readable, appears compressed. G Parted text although appears in whole is displayed all over the page instead of paragraph form, and Fedora 23 and Mint 17 have incomplete text on their screens similar to the Ubuntu 15.10 install.

Can anyone suggest a decent video card that will display Linux programs cleanly on the monitor while using either live CD's or hard drive installs.  I understand for advanced graphics applications I need to install proprietary drivers but just to get readable screens on Live CD's to run Ubuntu hard drive installs or use G Parted off the hard drive for partitioning should not be impossible as with the Nvidia GTX 745. I prefer a card with some heftiness to it because I am constantly researching on the web and some of these sites really stream a lot of advertisements which slows down the browsing on my older machines. I don't have an unlimited budget to plug and play with components but am coming around to the idea of swapping out a prepackaged video card with another if that is what it takes. I am just looking for some video card that will show basic Live CD screens without scrambling them up. From my research the Nvidia GTX 745 is not it.

Thank you
ZV Rotenberg

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to boot the live cd for the sake of installing it, then you can add `nomodeset` to the boot parameters.  For live CD's you usually need to select an "Advanced" option, but at some point you should be able to hit `e` to edit the boot parameters.

You will get a screen that will have a bunch of text, and one of the lines will start with `vmlinuz ...stuff.. quiet splash`.  Use your arrow keys to go to the end of the line and add `nomodeset` to that line, and hit `F10` to boot.  `stuff` should be the kernel version, and possibly some other flags.  This will boot it in "Simple Graphics Mode" which should work even without the NVIDIA drivers installed.  It will be very poor resolution, but you can at least function.

The only other alternative I have ever had success with was connecting the monitor to the motherboard output (rather than the GPU), and it usually doesn't even use the GPU.  Sometimes, though, you have to actually disconnect the GPU...which isn't a very practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try nouveau.modeset=0/inserted in grub boot string where just after word splash. It is a known issue with 15.10 and NVidia cards. Than after booting up install Ubuntu and after - install NVidia drivers from repository.